# Android - Renderscript Support Library - Error loading RS jni library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, renderscript

I am trying to include the Renderscript support library into my project. I am getting the following error.

```
android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load rsjni: findLibrary returned null
```

I am not using any Renderscript jar files, I am attempting to use it via Gradle.

Here are my Gradle.build files

TOP LEVEL

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
}
}

ext {
compileSdkVersion="Google Inc.:Google APIs:22"
buildToolsVersion="23.0.1"
playStoreMinSdkVersion=16
amazonStoreMinSdkVersion=8
targetSdkVersion=22
versionCode=20
versionName="3.3.0"
runProguard=true
zipAlign=true
proguardConfiguration='../proguard.config'
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Application Specific

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "**REMOVED**"
    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    versionName rootProject.ext.versionName

    renderscriptTargetApi 23
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
```

Everything I try & find as possible solutions on stackoverflow are not working. I also have this included in my proguard config

```
#RenderScript
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
native <methods>;
}
-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** { *; }
```

Edit: Here is the implementation where I actually use renderscript, also this is where it causes my app the crash when called.

```
public static BitmapDrawable Blur ( View view ){

    Bitmap image = GetScreenshot( view );

    int width = Math.round( image.getWidth() * DEFAULT_BITMAP_SCALE );
    int height = Math.round( image.getHeight() * DEFAULT_BITMAP_SCALE );

    Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( image, width, height, false );

    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( inputBitmap );

    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create( view.getContext() );
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur intrinsicBlur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create( rs, Element.U8_4(rs) );

    Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
    Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap( rs, outputBitmap );

    intrinsicBlur.setRadius( DEFAULT_BLUR_RADIUS );
    intrinsicBlur.setInput( tmpIn );
    intrinsicBlur.forEach( tmpOut );

    tmpOut.copyTo( outputBitmap );

    inputBitmap.recycle();
    rs.destroy();

    return new BitmapDrawable( outputBitmap );
}
```

This is the exact line

```
RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create( view.getContext() );
```

Comment: You should post more code related to the actual problem: where and how do you load the RS library, for example. Also your project configuration (where RS library is defined, its source etc) could probably also help

Comment: Are you trying to run the app on the device, or on the emulator?

Comment: This is on a physical Droid 3 with Android 2.3.4. It works well with a device running 5.0. I assume that's because it is not using the support library?

Comment: You probably need to decrease `renderscriptTargetApi` number to your actual target API (or minimum target API - try both). Currently you have `targetSdkVersion=22`, but renderscript target api set to 23. Seems fishy

Comment: I fixed the target API to level 22 to match my projects target API.. Seems to be the same issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately Renderscript is not available for the `armeabi` architecture. The bright side is that you can check at runtime to see the architecture of the device and not run the Renderscript code on those devices:

```
System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

There is also an issue open on the android bug tracker, where they state:

> We only ship the support library for armeabi-v7a. This is a known limitation.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68520

Edit: If you want to implement a blur without Renderscript on `armeabi` devices, you can simply downscale the image with `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` setting `filter` to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can solve that by unzipping your apk file, then check lib folder.
lib folder contains native libraries grouped by different system architectures (arm64-v8a, armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips, x86, etc).

Sometimes some libraries exist only for some system architectures not all architectures, so you need to check system architecture first before using any code from this native library for example Renderscript support library.

For Renderscript exception, you can do something like that

```
ArrayList<String> abis = new ArrayList<>();

 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   abis.add(Build.CPU_ABI);
 } else {
    for (String abi : Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS) {
        abis.add(abi);
    }
 }

 if (abis.contains("x86") || abis.contains("mips") || abis.contains("armeabi-v7a")) {
   // do Renderscript stuff
 }
```