# Using System.getProperty("os.arch") to check if it is armeabi cpu

Tags: android, cpu-architecture

I'm having the following issue with RenderScript on some old 4.2.2- devices (galaxy s3 mini, galaxy ace 3, galaxy fresh, etc.) - [Android - Renderscript Support Library - Error loading RS jni library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786838/android-renderscript-support-library-error-loading-rs-jni-library).

I want to implement the suggested solution but what exactly will be the value returned by

> System.getProperty("os.arch");

for **armeabi** devices (not armeabi-v7 devices).

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method `System.getProperty` is a generic method of Java, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)) you can find the documentation.

On Linux it returns the same value obtained from the command `uname -m`. The possible values are for example `armv5t`, `armv5te`, `armv5tej`, `armv5tejl`, `armv6`, `armv7`, `armv7l`, `i686` and many more. There isn't an exact value for the `armeabi` devices because it slightly differs from cpu to cpu.

There is a better alternative to `System.getProperty` and it is the field `Build.CPU_ABI` (or `Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS` in newer devices):

```
String abi = null;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    abi = Build.CPU_ABI;
} else {
    abi = Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS[0];
}
```

The possible values are `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`, `x86`, `x86_64`, `mips`, `mips64`.

As you can see the number of possible results is much lower than `System.getProperty`, and you can check directly for `armeabi`.

Comment: why you only getting first item of Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS by Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS[0] , it is supposed that all values are supported by this device, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. The most preferred ABI is the first element in the list, as you can see in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SUPPORTED_ABIS).