# Finding architecture info on linux/android kernel while building kernel code

Tags: android, architecture, linux-kernel, compile-time

I am making modification on the kernel files. I want to load one function if it is a 32 bit architecture or load another function if it is a 64 bit architecture. Is it possible to get architecture info in the kernel during build time and load different functions based on it. In which location is the architecture info stored or from where to get the info? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Property `System.getProperty("os.arch")` should be what you're looking for. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694596/using-system-getpropertyos-arch-to-check-if-it-is-armeabi-cpu) and [Android Developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html) for more info.

Comment: System.getProperty("os.arch") is used from the java layer. Is there a similar function that can be used in kernel code.

Comment: Isn't it then the same as in Linux? That means `uname -a`? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136407/is-my-linux-arm-32-or-64-bit