# (android) How can I make each list items blurred?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using this library to blur a view (https://github.com/Dimezis/BlurView/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml).

This library has the custsom view, the 'BlurView' and it blurs all underlying views dynamically even when the background image changes. It worked pretty well.

I wanted to implement it for my RecyclerView so that each item's background can blur the background of the activity. 
But the result came out like this: 
[image]

I think this library took a snapshot of the app screen and blurred it. You can see the Toolbar is blurred altogether. 
I want this blur effect to be dynamic so that it can blur the background real time when the user scrolls up and down. It worked fine as a single view but not as a list item.

Here's my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    PlanListAdapter adapter = new PlanListAdapter(this, getWindow().getDecorView(),new String[]{"Cookie", "Pie", "Banana split", "Peanut butter"});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**PlanListAdapter.java**

```
public class PlanListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {


    private String[] titles;
    private Context context;
    private View decorView;

    public PlanListAdapter(Context context, View decorView, String[] names) {
        super(context, -1);
        this.context = context;
        this.titles = names;
        this.decorView = decorView;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rootView = parent.getRootView();
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_planitem, null, false);
        BlurView blurView = (BlurView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.blur_item);
        blurView.setupWith(rootView)
                .windowBackground(decorView.getBackground())
                .blurAlgorithm(new RenderScriptBlur(context, true))
                .blurRadius(24f);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm the guy who developed this library.
I tried to reproduce this bug, but with RecyclerView setup, and I figured that BlurView can't get proper position on the screen if it's inside of the list.

You can actually fire an issue on Github, I will try to fix this thing in the nearest time. I believe there should be a workaround for similar cases using `View.getLocationOnScreen()`

**Edit:**
I've updated BlurView to 1.3.0 version, fix for your case is included.
Now position is properly calculated relative to rootView.

Answer (score 1):

All blur libraries use Renderscript library of Android and this is a bit problematic for some android phones (regardless of their android version)

Here is an runtime exception example that you can encounter:

```
android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException
SourceFile line 100 in BlurringView.a()
Error loading libRSSupport library
```

Since this is a native library you can't handle these errors. I encountered this error even on some models of Samsung Galaxy. So beaware of this and don't use blur libraries if you don't have to.

Here is more info about the subject:

[Android - Renderscript Support Library - Error loading RS jni library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786838/android-renderscript-support-library-error-loading-rs-jni-library)

If you really want to use blur on your views you can check this library. If you need more help, i can send you sample code of mine using this library.

https://developers.500px.com/a-blurring-view-for-android-7f33d41a047d#.nnl0sxpoz